# Understanding java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=X; regionStart=Y; regionLength=Z

Tags: java, android, string, stringindexoutofbounds

How to interpret a

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=30278; regionStart=6877; regionLength=-12
```

or better how to reproduce such an exception where

- `length` is positive,
- `regionStart` is positive and less than `length`
- and `regionLength` is negative?

What do these attributes mean at all? They aren't mentioned in the documentation of this exception.

I only know `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: X` where `X` is a negative integer.
Reproducable with:

```
String s = "hello world";
String chunk = s.substring(5, -8);
```

for example.

Asking because such an exception is thrown in my android app. But it is thrown very seldom. Otherwise I would set a breakpoint and see what is going on there.

```
        java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=30278; regionStart=6877; regionLength=-12
        at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:298)
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1087)
        ...
        my app specific calls here
        ...
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21342)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

As I know what action can lead to this exception I've set a breakpoint at that position and opened `String` class definition (because Android uses analogs of standard java classes sometimes) when the debugger stopped there. But the `String` class didn't contain `startEndAndLength` method...

Comment: @baao That is not a duplicate of this question

Comment: I don't see any `regionLength` in [String class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java) nor StringIndexOutOfBoundsException class, which suggests that it was created via `throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("length=" + length + ", regionStart=" + regionStart + ", regionLength=" + regionLength);` outside of that class. From where it was actually thrown? Can you provide some [mcve] and stacktrace?

Comment: Catch it and print its stack trace to see where it's thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I was able to catch the exception and can now deduce the meaning of the attributes mentioned.
So if you have an instruction like:

```
text.substring(start, end)
```

`length` will be the length of the `text` (or `text.length()`)

`regionStart` will be `start`

and `regionLength` will be (`end - start`)

When I look at it now, it looks simple, but if you see it first time it's not so clear as you usually see another message when `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

As define in the method definition If  the regionstart is bigger than regionend you will got this exception.